# Data in table disappears during navigation tabs using ligne paginate

Tags: javascript, html, pagination

I have a dashboard page that is loading information into multiple tables using ligne paginate. The hav different ID's and I am also navigating through my dashboard pane using divs with different ID's as well.

what is happening is when i load information from database it is paginating correctly (for example 500 rows showing more than 10 pages), but when i navigate within tabs the all the paginated tables start resorting to showing only two table pages instead of the original number of tablepages when it was intitially loaded (e.g two table pages instead of the ten table pages for one tab as an example).

this is my html div with one tab as an example :

```
<div id="Mother" class="tabcontent"  style="display:block">
<h2>Candidates Information</h2><br><br><br>
  <form method="post">
<div class="input-group">
                <label for="searchBoxMother">Search For Member&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <input type="search" id="searchBoxMother" placeholder="Type here ......">
            </div><br>
    <table class="myTableMother table hover" id = "myTableMother">
    <tbody>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>AGE</th>
</tr>

<tr><td>//TABLE DATA</td>
<td>//TABLE DATA</td>
<td>//TABLE DATA</td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
</form><br><br>
</div>
```

This is the one calling this specific div to display along with other tab contents:

```
<li class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mother');tableMother()"><a>General Information</a></li>
```

This is my javascript code that is sorting out the table

```
<script>
function tableMother(){
    let options = {
            numberPerPage:10, 
            goBar:true, 
            pageCounter:true,
        };

        let filterOptions = {
            el:'#searchBoxMother'
        };

        paginate.init('.myTableMother',options,filterOptions);
       
}
</script>
```

And this is the javascript code navigating through tabs with other tables like the one in the div above:

```
<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
      // Declare all variables
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
      
      // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }

      // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
      window.history.forward();
      document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }

</script>
```

I do not understand why its changing to only two pages when it originally has more than this.

Please help, your help much apprecitated and hopefully have provided enough info to get assistance.

............................................................